# jQuery Counter, animating to a total, but how do I include a comma?

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

I have a found a number of solutions on here for a counter, animating from one total to another.

Here's my what I'm using now:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
          ts : function (from, to, time) {
            var steps = 1,
                self = this,
                counter;
        
            if (from - to > 0) {
              steps = -1;
            };
        
            from -= steps;
        
            function step() {
              self.text(from += steps);
        
              if ((steps < 0 && to >= from) || (steps > 0 && from >= to)) {
                clearInterval(counter);
              };
            };
        
            counter = setInterval(step, time || 5);
          }
        });
        
        
        var total = $('.total').ts(56000,56941);
```

It works well.  However, I would like to add a comma to the total, something like 56,941. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work. The function is taken from http://ntt.cc/2008/04/25/6-very-basic-but-very-useful-javascript-number-format-functions-for-web-developers.html. Very handy

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
          ts : function (from, to, time) {
            var steps = 1,
                self = this,
                counter;

            if (from - to > 0) {
              steps = -1;
            };

            from -= steps;

            function step() {
              self.text(addCommas(from += steps));

              if ((steps < 0 && to >= from) || (steps > 0 && from >= to)) {
                clearInterval(counter);
              };
            };

            counter = setInterval(step, time || 5);
          }
        });


var total = $('.total').ts(56000,56941);


function addCommas(nStr)
{
  nStr += '';
  x = nStr.split('.');
  x1 = x[0];
  x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
  var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
  while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
  }
  return x1 + x2;
}
```

​

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will do it:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    ts: function(from, to, time) {
        var steps = 1, self = this, counter;

        if (from - to > 0) steps = -1;
        from -= steps;

        function step() {
            var x = (from += steps).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
            self.text(x);
            if ((steps < 0 && to >= from) || (steps > 0 && from >= to)) {
                clearInterval(counter);
            };
        };
        counter = setInterval(step, time || 5);
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ESBYb/1/)

Answer (score 1):

From somewhere on the web...

```
function formatComma(x){ 
    return (x+'').replace( /\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
}
```

I like my own solution of reversing the string better as it is easier to understand the logic...

```
function formatComma(x){
    // prepare the input as a string ready for manipulating and returning
    return (x+'')
      // reverse the string (by converting to array)
      .split("").reverse().join("")
      // replace 3 digits in a row, with themselves and a comma
      // so long as the digits are followed by a non-word boundary
      .replace(/(\d{3})\B/g,'$1,')
      // reverse it all again
      .split("").reverse().join("")
}
```

Comment: Please attribute code you found to (at least) where you found it, or the author!

Comment: nope, I found it a while ago, and saved it as a snippet - no idea where I got it, although a decent chance I found it here on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is! You can check this plugin (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/) and implement it in yours :-)